# C# asp email form - checkboxes return as null and won't send

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, null

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string _docValues = String.Join("<br>", Request.Form.GetValues("sendme"));
    string _vidValues = String.Join("<br>", Request.Form.GetValues("vidsend"));
}
```

I have an email form with two groups of html `checkboxes`. I'm gathering the values and putting them into their own strings `_docValues` and `_vidValues`. However, this form only sends if I check a checkbox from each of the groups. If I don't select something from `_docValues`, it gives me an error:

> Value cannot be null

How do I assign it a value, even if it's just a white space?

Comment: Why dont you give a default check box selection. And if the user want he can change the values.

Comment: Either setting a default value in `_docValues` with null-coalescing operator or mark a checkbox in `_docValues` group as `selected` by default may solve your issue.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried adding a "hidden" checkbox that's always checked for both groups, and while that works, I run into the issue of not being able to fully hide that hidden checkbox because I do a printout of values before the email sends. 

I'm not sure how to do a null-coalescing operator, as I'm pretty new with C#.

Comment: null-coalescing is Request.Form.GetValues("sendme") ?? string.Empty will give you an empty string rather than null

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Form.GetValues("sendme") != null && Request.Form.GetValues("vidsend") != null)
    {
        string _docValues = String.Join("<br>", Request.Form.GetValues("sendme"));
        string _vidValues = String.Join("<br>", Request.Form.GetValues("vidsend"));
    }
    else
    {
        string _docValues = "";
        string _vidValues = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: He will still have to answer both questions here for anything to happen. Better to check each one individually.

Comment: Oh no how absent-minded of me. Well you've already answered anyway. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

```
protected string _docValues = string.Empty;
protected string _vidValues = string.Empty;

protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Form["sendme"] != null)
        _docValues = String.Join("<br>", Request.Form.GetValues("sendme"));

    if (Request.Form["vidsend"] != null)
        _vidValues = String.Join("<br>", Request.Form.GetValues("vidsend"));
}
```

Comment: I did try this one, but I get an error later  for  
  

    `string body = this.createEmailBody(_recipient, _sender, _message, _docValues, _vidValues);` 

  The name '_docValues' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Then make the strings properties of the page instead so you can access them outside the event handler. I have modified the code.